# Subtle error with a module endormorphism on $\mathbb{Z}_8 \times \mathbb{Z}_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, quadratic-forms, exponential-sum

Let $a,b,c$ be arbitrary integers such that $a$ is odd and $(a,b,c)=1$.

Let $R = \mathbb{Z}_8$, the set of all integer residues modulo $8$. Define an $R$-module endomorphism $\phi \colon R \times R$ by
\begin{align*}
\phi(x,y) = (2ax+by,y)
\end{align*}

We have that $\ker(\phi) = \langle 4 \rangle \times \langle 0 \rangle$, where $\langle g \rangle$ is the principal ideal generated by $g$. By the 1st isomorphism theorem for modules, we have that
\begin{align*}
\phi(R \times R) \simeq (R \times R)/(\langle 4 \rangle \times  \langle 0 \rangle)
\end{align*}

One can now show that $\phi(R \times R) \simeq R/\langle 4 \rangle \times R$, see, for example, exercise 11, section 10.2 in Dummit and Foote.

Observe that $R/\langle 4 \rangle$ is a quotient module under the ring action
\begin{align*}
r(x + \langle 4 \rangle) = rx + \langle 4 \rangle.
\end{align*}

One can see that $ R/\langle 4 \rangle \simeq \langle 2 \rangle$ and so we deduce
\begin{align*}
\phi(R \times R) \simeq \langle 2 \rangle\times R
\end{align*}

Set $\displaystyle e(\alpha) = e^{2\pi \imath \alpha}$ for any rational number $\alpha$.

Observe that
\begin{align*}
4a(ax^2+bxy+cy^2) = (2ax+by)^2+(4ac-b^2)y^2.
\end{align*}

Hence, now consider the sum
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x,y=0}^{2-1} e\left(\frac{ax^2+bxy+cy^2}{2}\right) &= \left(\frac{1}{2^2}\right)^2 \sum_{x,y=0}^{8-1} e\left(\frac{ax^2+bxy+cy^2}2\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{2^4}\sum_{x,y=0}^{8-1} e\left(\frac{a^{-1}(4a)(ax^2+bxy+cy^2)}{8}\right)\\
&= \frac{1}{2^4}\sum_{y=0}^{8-1} e\left(\frac{a^{-1}(4ac-b^2)y^2}{8}\right) \sum_{x=0}^{8-1} e\left(\frac{a^{-1}(2ax+by)^2}{8}\right).
\end{align*}

By the isomorphism above, we can replace $2ax+by$ with $2x$, so that for arbitrary $y$, as $x$ runs over a complete residue system modulo $8$, $2x$ runs over an isomorphic set of residues to $2ax+by$. Hence, this yields

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2^4}\sum_{y=0}^{8-1} e\left(\frac{a^{-1}(4ac-b^2)y^2}{8}\right) \sum_{x=0}^{8-1} e\left(\frac{a^{-1}x^2}{2}\right)=0
\end{align*}

However, when we look at the sum itself, we have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{x,y=0}^{1} e\left(\frac{ax^2+bxy+cy^2}2\right) &= 1 + (-1)^a + (-1)^c + (-1)^{a+b+c}\\
&=(-1)^c(1+(-1)^{b-1}).
\end{align*}

This last expression is non-zero whenever $b$ is odd.

Thus, I have made a mistake somewhere in my module homomorphisms. I think the obvious mistake is that $2ax+by$ doesn't "behave" like $2x$ if $b$ is odd. But I don't see the error in the isomorphism above. Any help would be great!

Comment: Isn't the problem your assumption that if you sum a function over one set of residues and then an "isomorphic set of residues," you'll get the same answer both times?

Comment: It must be that.

My assumption is that, as we have an isomorphism, under $\phi$, $(2ax+by)$ will behave like $2x$ for all $x$ and arbitrary $y$. The structure is certainly the same, but their residue values modulo $8$ are different. Hence, as their residue values are not the same, we get different results.

That's it. The isomorphic set of residues has the same structure, but not the same values, and so these sums will be different.